# Circle selection instead of square

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like my selection to be a circle instead of a square (with the scale effect on hover) but border-radius doesn't seem to work, and I tried  without any success.

http://robinmastromarino.be/dataviz04/ It's just after "Ce que tu auras peut-être un jour ou l'autre..."

Here's the html :

```
<div id="tablerond">    
    <div id="tablerond4"></div>
    <div id="tablerond3"></div>
    <div id="tablerond2"></div>
    <div id="tablerond1"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the css for "tablerond2" (they all look alike)

```
#tablerond2 {
width: 438px;
height: 439px;
border-radius: 219px;
background: url(img/tablerond2.png);
position: absolute;
top: 87px;
left: 82px;
```

Comment: Pouvez-vous s'il vous plaît nous montrer votre codes?

Comment: Why not use an Image and then use a map element that is in the shape of a circle http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: @user1938671 Already tried a map element, didn't get it to work.